# ODATA Date Filter - Generating sql server query differently than expected - causing poor performance

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

When I pass date filter to Odata, its generating query as follows: causing poor performance

```
SELECT TOP(10000) [$it].[ID], Column1, ....
      FROM tablename AS [$it]
      WHERE (((DATEPART(year, [$it].[COBDate]) * 10000) + (DATEPART(month, [$it].[COBDate]) * 100)) + DATEPART(day, [$it].[COBDate])) = (((2020 * 10000) + (12 * 100)) + 4)
      ORDER BY [$it].[ID]
```

My question is: How to generate query as below for better performance?

```
SELECT TOP(10000) [$it].[ID], Column1, ....
      FROM tablename AS [$it]
      WHERE COBDate = '2020-12-04'
      ORDER BY [$it].[ID]
```

Technical Details:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4lbY.png

Odata Request:

https://localhost:5001/odata/Product?api-version=1.0&%24filter=COBDate%20Eq%202020-12-04

Model class:

```
public DateTime COBDate { get; set; }
```

Model Configuration:

```
product.Property(x => x.COBDate).AsDate();
```

Controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ODataValue<IEnumerable<Product>>), Status200OK)]
[ODataRoute("Product")]
[ConfigurableEnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(context.tablename.AsQueryable());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex, "Call failed.");
        return BadRequest($"{ex}");
    }
}
```

Comment: There are three versions of EF Core. Which failed?

Comment: no failure, background query is not generated as expected. anyway, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (2.2.6)

Comment: This has nothing to do with EF Core, because the predicate is generated by OData query processor.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your problem but direction what to do. Problem not with EF Core but with OData library itself.

I have analyzed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` source code and found this

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/955ee08511485f9b5ca46a4c9d6736a7e0357e85/src/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Shared/Query/Expressions/ExpressionBinderBase.cs#L835-L851

So OData generates this ineffective query and quick looking at the code shows that there is no way to configure that.

Probably you have to create issue on their Github page.

Comment: Thanks Svyatoslav Danyliv... Just want to think some workaround when there is date filter.